# How to get mail to work in Openshift wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, email, openshift

What do I need to do to get a wordpress site on Openshift to send email via e.g. the plugin contact form 7?

I've got 3 plugins installed - they are all on this page
http://letter-gilding.rhcloud.com/calligraphy/

They all say "mail sent" but in fact no mail is sent, not even to the spam folder.

Openshift does send some mail, though, because when the wordpress site was set up, the wordpress application send a "new wordpress site" mail.

Comment: Are you sure the emails aren't in the spam folder?

Comment: Yes, neither the addressee nor the sender have messages in the spam folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your emails are more than likely getting caught up in the spam filter.  To help guarantee deliver, it is suggested that you use a third party mail service, such as sendgrid, mailgun, or your own gmail/yahoo/outlook email.  You can even sign up for sendgrid using the marketplace: https://marketplace.openshift.com/apps/9628